# Minimizing query result size algorithm

Tags: postgresql, bigdata

### Some context

Right now the client sends a request trying to get all data from chosen date to now to display it on the chart, it works nice 90% of the time, but sometimes the result query size can go up to 20 million rows which is absolutly predictalbe works realy slow, so now I am working on how can I display the data somehow reducing size of the result data

### Questions

1. What is the fastest way to count number of result rows to decide should i use some kind of minimizing alghoritm or not? I assume when speaking about data that big any minimizing could be helpfull
2. What could be an algorithm to present data on a chart fast enough? Right now I've only came up with dividing the request in N parts, count some average value for each of them and display avarage values on a chart, it would help to represent the date,but counting avarage value of million rows would still take up a lot of time

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a requirement to *get all data from chosen date to now*. This does not allow you to minimize the result and doing so would present the user with **false** information which (imho) is much, much worse than slow. Perhaps a better approach is to set a threshold at which you ask the user if they wish to continue and allow then to continue or not. Now counting each time would be much too slow, but there is a alternative: Create a Materialized View, refreshed daily, with the date and count for that date. Now instead of selecting directly select first form the MV.  If the result exceeds a establish threshold ask the user for confirmation. This will have a slowing effect on all requests, but for relative few rows it should not be too bad.  This then allows you to gather statistics on rows vs response time and give the user a estimated time for the result. *I have found users typically do not mind waiting, **if you can tell them in advance.*** See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0292a45fdd385152675608c70059082a): You did not provide table definition so I just made something up.

```
create materialized view all_data_summary as
       select the_date, count(*) num_items
         from all_data
        group by the_date;  
       
select sum(num_items) 
  from all_data_summary 
 where the_date between :user_date and current_date;
```